# python define one place use everywhere

Tags: python-3.x

In one python script:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.warning("This is a test error message for my first doing it")
```

How to use the same config in other python script? should I call `logging.config.dictConfig(config)` in every python script? So far I have only used python as a single standalone python script. This question is not merely about logging, but also other configuration that is defined once but used everywhere like database connector.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'everywhere' you mean in other modules, a good place to look for an answer is in the Logging Cookbook that is part of the Python Docs. The very first subject is ['Using logging in multiple modules'](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook).

Basically, what it says is that as long as you **call your logger something**, say

`logging.getLogger('someLogger')`

you can call it (the same object) from other modules.